# How to update redux store for many components at the same time on click of a single button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have four stateful react components in a single page, they get updated simultaneously on the click of a single button.

I now want to use redux store to save the state of all the components.

I wrote react-redux connect for the first component and it works fine.

Then followed the same logic for the second component, but the store is not getting updated along with the first one.

How can I save the states of all the components at same time to store?

Comment: I don't kind of follow with your problem here. What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you just wrap all your components into own `connect` export and map redux state to them? Redux will automatically take care that if redux store changes component updates. If you are going to do this repetitive just wrap components around HOC which does this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this kind of structure.

The main page in which you are using the four stateful components should look like this.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { commonState, updateCommonStateHandler } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <Component1 commonState={commonState} updateCommonStateHandler={updateCommonStateHandler} />
                <Component2 commonState={commonState} updateCommonStateHandler={updateCommonStateHandler} />
                <Component3 commonState={commonState} updateCommonStateHandler={updateCommonStateHandler} />
                <Component4 commonState={commonState} updateCommonStateHandler={updateCommonStateHandler} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        commonState: state.commonState
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        updateCommonStateHandler: change => {
            dispatch(() => ({
                type: 'UPDATE_COMMON_STATE',
                change
            }));
        }
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

With the reducer

```
const updateCommonStateReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    const newState = extend({}, state);
    if(action.type === 'UPDATE_COMMON_STATE') {
        newState.commonState = newState.commonState || {};
        extend(newState.commonState, action.change || {});
    }
    return newState;
};
```

So if you want to update the state from any child component, you should call the `updateCommonStateHandler`, which will dispatch an action to update the state.

On state update react will re-render all the components with new `commonState`.

> PS: This is just a sample code explaining the situation, not the solution and it's
>   written in ES6